# What is the meaning of "ذ‌‍ٰلك" in Quran 2:2?

Tags: tafseer, arabic, quran-translation, arabic-translation

Assalamu Alaikum,

What is the meaning of "ذ‌‍ٰلك" in Quran 2:2? Many or even all Quran translaters have translated it as "This". But in an Arabic-English I found Arabic word for "This" is "ذا" or "هذا". And word "ذٰلك" in not present in the dictionary and it appears to be a combination of two words; "ذا" (this) and "لك" (yours). So why it is not translated as "This yours"?

Please can you explain me its real meaning or why/how it is translated as "This", as I have very less knowledge of Arabic language.

I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It is **ذَلِكَ**  not **لَكَ** - kasrah not fathah on laam. These are totally unrelated words. ذَلِكَ means "that" - however it is also used to substitute for هَذَا "this". The translations give the correct meaning.

Comment: Thank you! Agree with "kasrah not fathah on laam" but you said "dhalika" means "that", but it is translated to "this", when you read some popular translations, e.g. Mohsin Khan, Yousaf Ali, Picthal. And also give a reference to the word "dhalika" in any dictionary.